# Twilio Studio - Select and Parse JSON Using Liquid

Tags: twilio, liquid

In Twilio Studio, I'm making a GET request and am trying to parse JSON and subsequently assign variables based on the parsed JSON. I'm having difficulty doing so with the JSON that is returned.

Essentially I'm trying to set variables from the "Row" that matches the returned JSON (a user dials in, enters their PIN {{widgets.PIN_Entry.Digits}}, the PIN will match a "Row" in the returned JSON from the GET request and we set variables for userID, userEmail, userName, userPin for the matched row).

```
{
  "DataSource": {
    "Id": "12345",
    "Name": "Dial-In Subscribers",
    "Rows": [
      [
        "EMP-0226",
        "ron@pawneeil.com",
        "Ron Swanson",
        "00054321"
      ],
      [
        "EMP-0267",
        "leslie@pawneeil.com",
        "Leslie Knope",
        "00012345"
      ]
    ],
    "TotalRows": 2,
    "LastUpdated": "2020-08-26T03:39:42.7670000Z",
    "CompanyId": 12345
  }
}
```

I can easily do this with JSON Path (not supported by Twilio studio) to select the values I'm looking to set as variables, but I can't figure out how to use Liquid to do this.

> userID == $.DataSource.Rows[?(@.includes('00012345'))].[0]

(would return "EMP-0267")

> userEmail == $.DataSource.Rows[?(@.includes('00012345'))].[1]

(would return "leslie@pawneeil.com")

> userName == $.DataSource.Rows[?(@.includes('00012345'))].[2]

(would return "Leslie Knope)

> userPin == $.DataSource.Rows[?(@.includes('00012345'))].[3]

(would return "00012345")

Can anyone share some ideas on how to parse the JSON and set variables using Liquid? Here's how I'm thinking I would accomplish this:

1. Match the variable {{widgets.PIN_Entry.Digits}} to a row in the returned JSON
2. Parse the selected row and set variables for userID, userEmail, userName, userPin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [Run Function Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/run-function) in these cases, I find it much easier to deal with then the nuances of Liquid Syntax.

```js
    // Description
    // Make a read request to an external API
    
    // Add axios 0.20.0 as a dependency under Functions Settings, Dependencies
    const axios = require('axios');
    
    exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
      
      let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
      
      // Arrays start at 0
      let selectedDigit = 0;
    
      axios
        .get(`https://x.x.x.x/myAPI`)
        .then((response) => {
          
          let { Rows } = response.data.DataSource;
    
          let result = Rows.filter((record, index) => index === selectedDigit);
          twiml.say(`The result is ${result}`);
          
          return callback(null, twiml);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          return callback(error);
        });
    };
```